# shell_exec() not running full command

Tags: php, python, shell, shell-exec

The python code expects 4 arguments, and in error.log is complaining that it isn't getting all of them (index error for sys.argv[3] and [4]). What I've noticed is that print_r($command) will print the full command as expected in the console:

```
python3 ../TD/login.py someuser somepass XXXX 1.0
```

But when I try to manually run the code by copy and pasting it from the browser console to the shell, the paste from clipboard cuts off right after "somepass", thus I'm missing the last two arguments. I have a feeling this is why the python is complaining when executed by the PHP also, but I'm unsure how to fix it. The code in question is below:

```
$tdPlainPass = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$storePass,$row["td_pass"],MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$row["td_salt"]);
$command = "python3 ../TD/login.py " . $row["td_user"] . " " . $tdPlainPass . " XXXX 1.0";
print_r($command);
$resultJSON = json_decode(shell_exec($command), true);
print_r($resultJSON);
return;
```

As an extra, if I encapsulate the string with escapeshellcmd(), it will no longer even print the last two arguments at print_r($command); Might be useful?

Comment: stop chaning your calls. if the exec fails, then you pass whatever invalid output is coming from exec into json_decode, which when fail as well. never EVER assume that a request to an external service will succeed. always check for failure. e.g. `$foo = shell_exec(); did_foo_fail(); json_decode($foo);`

Comment: For testing purposes the above code is sufficient. I need to figure out what's causing the larger bugs before I spend time adding in the rest.

Comment: if you say you have problems copying the full command string, try adding a `trim($tdPlainPass)` and see how it goes. Maybe a special character gets in the way